# SQL Query that returns all missing months for date ranges within a year (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, date-range

An employee is hired for different departments. For example, they could be working in Marketing and be paid by Department 0001 and also Department 0002 depending on the hours they do. For this question, hours doesn't matter as I truly only need to find the date ranges when the employee is NOT hired. The below two employees are examples of those.

| Employee_ID | Department_ID | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 395961 | 0001 | 01/01/2022 | 03/31/2022 |
| 395961 | 0002 | 01/01/2022 | 01/31/2022 |
| 395961 | 0001 | 06/01/2022 | 10/31/2022 |
| 395961 | 0001 | 11/01/2022 | 12/31/2022 |
| 395962 | 0001 | 01/01/2022 | 03/31/2022 |
| 395962 | 0002 | 01/01/2022 | 01/31/2022 |
| 395962 | 0002 | 02/01/2022 | 04/30/2022 |
| 395962 | 0001 | 06/01/2022 | 10/31/2022 |
| 395962 | 0001 | 11/01/2022 | 12/31/2022 |
| 395963 | 0001 | 01/01/2022 | 05/31/2022 |
| 395963 | 0002 | 06/01/2022 | 12/31/2022 |

Employee_ID 395961 and 395962 should return for the query as both have date range gaps. 395961 does not have a date range from 04/01/2022 until 05/31/2022. 395962 does not have a date range from 05/01/2022 until 05/31/2022. 395963 does NOT have a date range gap.

I had in mind to return the months the employee had date ranges and group them by month as we can get duplicate returns. For example, Employee_ID 395961 would return Jan, Feb, March, Jan, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec and when we group the months, it would remove the duplicate Jan. Then we check which months are missing and if anything returns, we should consider to return this Employee_ID as result.

I truly have NOT figured out how to get a correct result, but I've done some research to find the below that could help. I wouldn't want to use variables as I want this query applied to 1000's of records.

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @Start_Date)) AS MonthName
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @Start_Date, @End_Date)
```

Edit: The database is Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Your question is tagged mysql, but the table reference `master.dbo.spt_values` makes me think you are using Microsoft SQL Server (because MySQL doesn't support such catalog-qualified identifiers). Can you please query `SELECT @@version;` and confirm which database software you are using?

Comment: Also are yur dates really held as strings?

Comment: @BillKarwin Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: @RiggsFolly - No, they are dates in CCYY-MM-DD format. The query I provided was only an example on how to get the months from a date range... but truly that's not what I needed. I don't even know where to start, so I just gave something as reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should give you what you are looking for:

```sql
WITH cal (date) AS (
    SELECT @Start_Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, date)
    FROM cal
    WHERE date < @End_Date
)
SELECT e.Employee_ID, COUNT(cal.date) AS Days_Not_Hired
FROM cal
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Employee_ID FROM employees) e
LEFT JOIN employees e2
    ON cal.date BETWEEN e2.Start_Date AND e2.End_Date
    AND e.Employee_ID = e2.Employee_ID
WHERE e2.Employee_ID IS NULL
GROUP BY e.Employee_ID
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 365);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OdpbGbIn)

This is targeted at SQL Server. It may need tweaking for other dialects.

---

To run for all employees for all time you could do:

```sql
WITH cal (date) AS (
    SELECT MIN(Start_Date) FROM employees
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, date)
    FROM cal
    WHERE date < CAST( GETDATE() AS DATE )
)
SELECT e.*, COUNT(cal.date) AS Days_Not_Hired
FROM cal
JOIN (
    SELECT
        Employee_ID,
        MIN(Start_Date) AS Min_Start_Date,
        MAX(End_Date) AS Max_End_Date
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY Employee_ID
) e
    ON cal.date BETWEEN e.Min_Start_Date AND e.Max_End_Date
LEFT JOIN employees e2
    ON cal.date BETWEEN e2.Start_Date AND e2.End_Date
    AND e.Employee_ID = e2.Employee_ID
WHERE e2.Employee_ID IS NULL
GROUP BY e.Employee_ID, e.Min_Start_Date, e.Max_End_Date
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XTFw7Rkq)

I very rarely use SQL Server so I have no idea how its optimiser is going to deal with this query.

Comment: Variables Start_Date and End_Date are used. Won't work for my scenario @nnichols

Comment: I declared the Start_Date and End_Date of 2022-01-01 and 2022-12-31 and received 1 employee back while it should have returned 2 employees.

Comment: I figured out why. My End Date was updated to 2022-04-31 when I CTRL+Z'd on another piece of code. I'm going to review some more records! Will get back if I have more questions! @nnichols

Comment: Obviously, you can run it without using user defined variables - https://dbfiddle.uk/_sdVjLNj

Comment: If I wanted to make sure it actually looked for a date gap between the MIN(START_DATE) and MAX(END_DATE) for the EMPLOYEE ID instead of Jan 2022 - Dec 2022, what is something that would have to be changed? For example. If it's from 2022-03-01 and 2022-12-31, it wouldn't have a date gap between those MIN/MAX dates. @nnichols

Comment: Those date ranges would change depending on Employee ID, right? So one employee may be there from Jan until Dec and other Employee may only start from March until Dec. I honestly have never used CROSS JOIN or rCTE or CTE in general. I plan on doing some research and playing around with it to understand what the query is exactly doing. I'm more of an analyst that reviews data compared to cleaning data or developing code. But I'm learning from what different sources provide me and I modify to what I need.

Comment: SELECT MIN(START_DATE), MAX(END_DATE) FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID is what I'm referring to. We are talking about 2mil records. @nnichols

Comment: That query ran and I'm verifying results. Appreciate it, @nnichols!